# Проблема с телеграмм ботом

Tags: python, telegram-bot

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

# создаем экземпляр бота
bot = telebot.TeleBot('token')


# обработка команды /start
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_handler(message):
    global markup
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Помощь")
    markup.add(btn1)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет, чтобы увидеть список комманд введите /help", reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def text(message):
    global markup
    if (message.text == "Помощь"):
        help(message)
    if (message.text == "Купи слона"):
        ks(message)
    if (message.text == "⛔Стоп игра⛔"):
        sgame(message)
    if (message.text == "⬅Назад⬅"):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Возвращаюсь", reply_markup=markup)



@bot.message_handler(commands=["help"])
def help(message):
    global markup1
    markup1 = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    btn2 = types.KeyboardButton("Купи слона")
    btn3 = types.KeyboardButton("⬅Назад⬅")
    markup1.add(btn2, btn3)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вот список моих комманд:",reply_markup=markup1)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['kupislona'])
def ks(message):
    global is_run
    global markup2
    markup2 = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    btn2 = types.KeyboardButton("⛔Стоп игра⛔")
    markup2.add(btn2)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Игра запущена.Купи Слона.",reply_markup=markup2)
    is_run = True
    while is_run:
        @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
        def reply(message):
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Все говорят {message.text}, а ты купи слона')

@bot.message_handler(commands=["stopgame"])
def sgame(message):
    global markup
    global is_run
    is_run = False
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Игра остановлена", reply_markup=markup)
    pass


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Основная проблема заключается с функцией `ks`.
Бот отвечает, что игра запущена, входит в цикл, но не входит в функцию `reply` .

Подскажите, как можно исправить.

Answer (score 0):

Вы уже создавали Handler сообщений в функции text с content_types=['text']

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]